# 128x64 OLED not working on 3.3v

Tags: power-supply, 3.3v

As the title suggests, I bought a 128x64 OLED display that would not work when powered by 3.3v. The description said that the OLED can be powered by a 3v-5v source, but I have only been able to get it working with 5v. The current development board I am using only outputs 3.3v, and I have not been able to successfully power the OLED. How can I fix this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: simply get a 5V power source or get an OLED display that works at 3.3V

Comment: Question needs at minimum a part number and link to data sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on specific module that you've bought. Many of them based on [SSD1306](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SSD1306) which uses 1.65~3.3V for logic. However it needs at least 7V for panel, which *might* work from 5V.

Not all lost though, since SSD1306Z has internal charge pump that can generate required voltage from logic supply. All it needs are 2 1.0uF capacitors connected between C1P/C1N and C2P/C2N pins. Many modules have them installed or at least have pads for them. Check your board.

Here is typical OLED module found on the web. I marked capacitors connected to pins 2-3 and 3-4.
[image]

Comment: I checked. It's working now. My guess is that I was sending 5v signals while powering the device with 3v and that didn't sit well. Now that I have fixed that, it is working again!

Comment: `Now that I have fixed that` ... what did you do?